# Desktop Environment (GNOME) seems to be broken on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, 22.04

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. When turning on my laptop today I discovered that some of the keys on my keyboard didn't work anymore, and I had to use the screen keyboard to input my password. I did a quick `update && upgrade` to see if that'd fix it. It did fix my keyboard issue.

I find myself however that my DE is broken and some of the things don't work. I can, for example, no longer write after pressing the home key to search for apps. And the styling of the windows manager is really off, as shown here: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afeND.jpg).

The only things I remember doing last night before shutting down my PC was updating some packages. Even though I don't remember that well, I'm pretty sure there was one related to gnome, so I'm thinking it might have something to do with that. (For context, I just executed `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`).

Any help on how I could fix this? I'm completely lost.

Edit: I already tried reinstalling gnome through apt-get --reinstall install, but it did nothing.

Comment: Do some simple troubleshooting to rule out a hardware fault: Test those keys in a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment.

Comment: If you were using a terminal when updating your package you can see your bash history: `nano ~/.bash_history`. Copy paste it in your question.

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 I just checked the `.bash_history` file and indeed the only relevant thing there is the `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` command I executed yesterday. I don't feel there's much information to get from that.

Comment: @JanaL then you can see what it installed via the `apt history file`, it is located here: `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 Sadly there's no information there either. I think that while trying to apply some random solution I found while googling, I cleaned those logs, so now only logs from today appear :`)

Comment: Try to logout and click on the wheel (at the bottom right if i remember) and change to `GNOME` (on wayland or xorg)

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 yes, that did it! Thank you so much. I still don't understand what happened, but at least most things are back to normal.

Comment: Well done. I think that an update brings back other desktop environment, i suppose the `classic gnome` was selected as default and you did not notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logout.
Click on the wheel (at the bottom right of the screen) in order to change the desktop environment. Select `GNOME` or `GNOME on xorg`.